# git commit and user identity

Tags: git

I am following the official guide of GIT, and actually I am at 2.2.6 paragraph " Committing Your Changes"
Previously, at section 1.5.1 "Identity" when asked to enter a command like

```bash
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
```

I missed the --global option because I don't need it.
Now everytime I do a git commit, I obtain

```
$git commit

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

but I do not want to enter a --global option, does exist another way?

Comment: Did you set both `user.email` and `user.name`?  Can you show the contents of `.git/config` for your project?

Comment: You have the answer in your question: `Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.`

Comment: @CarlNorum

[user]
        name = Caterpillar
        email = caterpillarDummyEmail@dummyemail.com

Comment: Are you sure that's from the same repo where you're trying to do the commit?

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes, it is the first time I use it and I don't have any other repos

Answer (score 24):

If you just want to set it for that repository, run:

```bash
git config user.email "you@example.com"
git config user.name "Your Name"
```

Comment: If using a shared (cloud) build machine for which we don't want to set the identity globally or locally for the repo, how can it be specified just for the single commit command?

Answer (score 6):

Just type the same name that you have in your GitHub account, the same the same letters and character.

[image: GitHub account name]

[image: git user.name]

Answer (score 1):

This is Solving

```bash
1- git init
2- git config user.name "AccountName"
3- git config user.email "yourGamil"
4- git add *
5- git commit -m "WriteCommit"
6- git push origin master
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question.

Comment: @Andy J, it did solve my problem on my mac m1. inside a dir named github/ I did the git init and all the other steps up til the 3rd. It worked like a charm.